# Powershell function not executing as expected

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

I have the following function that shows if any of the words in an `array` are contained in a `string`:

```
function AnyOf ([string] $line, [string[]] $list)
{
    Write-Output "AnyOf!"
    foreach($item in $list)
    {   
        if($line.Contains($item))
        {
            Write-Output "Found: $item" 
            return $true
        }
    }
    return $false
}
```

And this to test it:

```
function main
{   
    [string[]]$a = @("user1", "user2")
    $str = "user1 and user2"
    $res = AnyOf($str, $a)
}
```

I expect it to see both `user1` and `user2` to get printed out but nothing is printed. It appears as though the function isn't getting called because the `Write-Output "AnyOf!"` is never executed.

However, when I execute:

```
AnyOf($str, $a)
```

Instead of:

```
$res = AnyOf($str, $a)
```

I can see that the function is called but the iteration doesn't seem to happen... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things,

First of all, functions in powershell are not called using `()` you would call the function as

`AnyOf $str $a`

The standard convention is `$<<nameOfFunction>> <<param1>> <<param2>>`

Secondly, your output is being captured in `$res` and therefore not printed to the screen, if you add `$res` at the end of your `main function` it will output.

So your main function becomes:

```
function main
{   
    [string[]]$a = @("user1", "user2")
    $str = "user1 and user2"
    $res = AnyOf $str $a
    $res #or just don't assign it to $res..
}


#to call main:
main

Output:

AnyOf!
Found: user1
True
```

As you can see in the above output it never finds `User2` because you use a `return $true` once it finds a match, exiting out of the function.

Another thing to note is that when you `return $false` or `$true` these actually become part of the output stream, which might not be what you want as it can lead to unexpected behavior.